# Branch Options in MIPS32

Tags: assembly, mips32

I am trying to write a menu in my main method in MIPS32 that will branch to different labels, but for some reason I am getting an error that says: instruction references unidentified symbol jal L1.  Can someone please tell me if I'm doing my branching incorrectly or if my problem likely lies somewhere else?  Here's parts of my code:

```
.text
.globl main

main:
    addi $a0, 0, 10
    addi $a1, 0, 8

    slt $t1, $a1, $a0       # $a1>$a0
    beq $t1, 1, main_loop

    beq $a0, 0, case0       # $a0=0     

    beq $a1, 0, case1       # $a1=0 

    beq $a0, $a1, case1     # $a0=$a1

    slt $t1, $a0, $a1       # $a0<$a1
    beq $t1, 0, case0

main_loop:
    jal L1
    # MORE CODE

L1: 
    # MORE CODE

case0:
    # CODE WITH SYSCALL
    # print str
    jr $ra

case1:
    # CODE WITH SYSCALL
    # print str
    jr $ra

else:
    # print str
    # CODE WITH SYSCALL

.data
str: 
    .asciiz "message "
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue you describe with the code you've posted. You've got some other errors though; the two `addi` instructions at the top are incorrect (`addi` takes two register operands and an immediate, not one register operand and two immediates).

Comment: @Michael You are absolutely correct, I had that correct in my code but typed it incorrectly here.  Generally speaking, what is the cause when the assembler complains that a label does not exist, when it does?

Comment: I'm not sure if there's something that can be said in general. If the assembler says that the label doesn't exist then it usually really doesn't exist.

Comment: @Michael Hah well it does exist that's why I'm literally crying in a room by myself.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have DOS line-endings or some other unprintable character in your label definition or reference?/